# Javascript concat is not a function

Tags: javascript

Hi this code is not working I get error concat is not a function: how can I fix it?

```html
var o=[{r:[3,8]},{r:[2,3,4]}];
undefined
var R=o.reduce(function(x,y,z){ return x.concat(y.r);})
VM200964:1 Uncaught TypeError: x.concat is not a function
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `x` is an Object. The Object prototype doesn't have the `concat` function.

Comment: If you're looking to join all the arrays into one, I'd do this: `[].concat(...o.map(obj => obj.r))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to init the `x` as array `[]` on the second parameter of `reduce`

If you won't specify the initial value (second parameter), it will use the first element of your array as `x`. Which is an object and object has no `concat` function.

ES6 snippet

```js
var o=[{r:[3,8]},{r:[2,3,4]}];

var R=o.reduce((x,y) => x.concat(y.r) , []);
 
console.log( R );
```

Can also use:

```
var R=o.reduce(function(x,y,z){ return x.concat(y.r);},[]);
```

Doc: [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

`reduce()` iterates over the list `o` which contains objects. You do not provide an initial value as the second argument to `reduce()`, so the first item in the list is used. This means you are trying to call `concat()` on an object. But the objects do not have `concat()` as a function. You need to provide an initial empty array:

```
var R=o.reduce(function(x,y,z){ return x.concat(y.r);}, [])
```